# How to show the fixpoint iteration of a function converges? EDITED

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Let $g(x)=2x-e^{-x}$. For a function $G(x)$ such that $G(x)=x-\alpha g(x)$, how to show the fixpoint iteration of $G(x)$ converges for all $\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<2/3$?

I couldn't find any useful theorems for general iteration. I only know a bit about the error estimate for Newton's method and bisection method. But the question did not mention any method to use and also it did not give the explicit expression for $g(x)$.

Is there any way to approach the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need more information about the function $g$ and possibly the starting point $x_0$. If there are *no* restrictions, then a counterexample to the hypothesis is given by $g(x) = 4x$ for which 
\begin{equation}
G(x) = x - \alpha g(x) = (1-4\alpha)x
\end{equation} 
and $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ induces the iteration 
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1} = G(x_n) = -x_n
\end{equation}
which is not convergent unless we pick $x_0 = 0$.